# "Unable to connect to data source" Debian unixODBC FreeTDS; PHP CLI works, apache/web doesn't

Tags: debian, sql-server, apache-2.4, freetds, unixodbc

Envoironment:

webserver: Debian8 with Apache, PHP, unixODBC, FreeTDS 
(current versions installed with apt-get last week)

dataserver: Windows Server 2008 with MS SQL Server 2008

Opening this in webbrowser:
(variables are set and right)

```
<?php
    $connect = odbc_connect($db_server,$db_user,$db_password);
    var_dump($connect);
```

I get:

> Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL
>   Server]Unable to connect to data source, SQL state S1000 in SQLConnect
>   in /var/www/html/test/index.php on line 11 bool(false)

Running the same file/code in command line results in:

> resource(4) of type (odbc link)

Since i've read this could have something to do with SElinux
i tried typing `sestatus` in command line resulting in

> bash: sestatus: Command not found.

tsql/isql is also working.

Where do i have to make adjustments to allow apache to connect to the MSSQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

To allow apache to communicate with the MSSQL, you should do the following:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db on
```

In a couple of seconds you will be connected.

Comment: bash: setsebool: Command not found.

Comment: Worked for me after running around for days.